# Having touchevents work on 2.3 using ObjectAnimator

Tags: android, view, translate-animation, objectanimator

so first let me give you some context into what I'm trying to do and what I have tried :)
I have up to ten views that I need to move from right to left constantly. Once one view leaves the screen another one comes in from the right. All the views need to be touchable. I was able to achieve this a few ways but they were not smooth (some stuttered, others seemed to jump when the app slowed down). All of these views are in a viewGroup and I'm reusing them (just 10 views).

These are the ways I tried:

1. Changing the margins of the views (updated using handler)
2. Calling View.layout(l,t,r,b) (updated using handler)
3. Getting the View.getDrawingCache() and drawing it on a surfaceView (also using a handler)
4. Using ObjectAnimator (nineoldandroids)

None of them worked very smooth (views will stop for a fraction of a second and jump) but the best was using animations. I first used the regular translateAnimation from android but of course that is not touchable. I tried getting the matrix of the animation(I dont know if am doing something wrong) but it doesn't return the top/left of the view:

```
Transformation outTransformation = new Transformation();
      getTransformation(System.currentTimeMillis(), outTransformation);
      Matrix transformationMatrix = outTransformation.getMatrix();
      float[] matrixValues = new float[9];
      transformationMatrix.getValues(matrixValues);
      float transX = matrixValues[2];
      float transY = matrixValues[5];
```

So now my question.

The best result I got was using the ObjectAnimator.

```
mAnimation[index] = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mViews[index], "translationX", -left);
            mAnimation[index].setDuration(time);
            mAnimation[index].setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            mAnimation[index].addListener(mAnimatorListener);
            mAnimation[index].start();
```

I was able to have touches using ObjectAnimator but only with android 3.0 and up (not 2.3).

Does anyone know why or how I can have the touches work on android 2.3?
Or is there a better way to move all these views?
What are some things I should keep in mind or do when moving/animating so many views?

Do you have any idea how I could improve the "smoothness" (stutters or stops for a fraction of a second and jumps to catch up) of using any of the other options mentioned above?

Is ViewGroup the best to use? Sorry for so many question.

Any thoughts, ideas, or comments will be super helpful and very appreciated :)
And if you have more questions or don't understand something let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I just found your question, cause I run into the same problem. I have a layout full of buttons, and I use the ObjectAnimator from [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) to move it. If the API is >= 11 then everything is working fine, and all buttons are clickable to their NEW position. However, if the API < 11 then although the layout moves, buttons are not clickable in their new positions, but rather in their old ones. Check also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15132980/android-objectanimator-in-not-working?rq=1) answer.