# Android - Moving button using ObjectAnimator is not working

Tags: android, animation, objectanimator

I need to move button from one position to another. View position moving works fine but only the old area is clickable.

this is my code:

```
 Button animatorButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.animatorbutton);
 ObjectAnimator objectAnimatorButton = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(animatorButton, "translationX", 0f, 400f);
 objectAnimatorButton.setDuration(1000);
 objectAnimatorButton.start();
```

How can I move the button disabling the old clickable area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What android version are you using? Prior to 3.0 you need to manually move your view after the animation is complete in order to move the clickable area. See this response as reference" [How to do interactive animation (translation) with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595881/how-to-do-interactive-animation-translation-with-android) .

In 3.0 and newer the PropertyAnimator will also move the clickable area. Are you using the nineoldandroid animation package on a pre 3.0 device? If so you will only see the effects of the view animation and not the full effect of the properties (aka clickable area) moving.